# Dagster: Multiple and Conditional Outputs (Type check failed for step output xxx PySparkDataFrame)

Tags: dagster

I'm executing the Dagster tutorial, and I got stuck at the [Multiple and Conditional Outputs](https://docs.dagster.io/tutorial/basics_solids#multiple-and-conditional-outputs) step.

In the `solid` definitions, it asks to declare (among other things):

```
output_defs=[
    OutputDefinition(
        name="hot_cereals", dagster_type=DataFrame, is_required=False
    ),
    OutputDefinition(
        name="cold_cereals", dagster_type=DataFrame, is_required=False
    ),
],
```

But there's no information where the `DataFrame` cames from.
Firstly I have tried with `pandas.DataFrame` but I faced the error: `{dagster_type} is not a valid dagster type`. It happens when I try to submit it via `$ dagit -f multiple_outputs.py`.
Then I installed the `dagster_pyspark` and gave a try with the `dagster_pyspark.DataFrame`. This time I managed to summit the DAG to the UI. However, when I run it from the UI, I got the following error:

```
dagster.core.errors.DagsterTypeCheckDidNotPass: Type check failed for step output hot_cereals of type PySparkDataFrame.
  File "/Users/bambrozio/.local/share/virtualenvs/dagster-tutorial/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dagster/core/execution/plan/execute_plan.py", line 210, in _dagster_event_sequence_for_step
    for step_event in check.generator(step_events):
  File "/Users/bambrozio/.local/share/virtualenvs/dagster-tutorial/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dagster/core/execution/plan/execute_step.py", line 273, in core_dagster_event_sequence_for_step
    for evt in _create_step_events_for_output(step_context, user_event):
  File "/Users/bambrozio/.local/share/virtualenvs/dagster-tutorial/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dagster/core/execution/plan/execute_step.py", line 298, in _create_step_events_for_output
    for output_event in _type_checked_step_output_event_sequence(step_context, output):
  File "/Users/bambrozio/.local/share/virtualenvs/dagster-tutorial/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dagster/core/execution/plan/execute_step.py", line 221, in _type_checked_step_output_event_sequence
    dagster_type=step_output.dagster_type,
```

Does anyone know how to fix it? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

As Arthur pointed out, the full tutorial code is available on Dagster's [github](https://github.com/dagster-io/dagster/blob/4a91c9d09b50db93e9174c93a4ada0e138e3a046/examples/docs_snippets/docs_snippets/intro_tutorial/basics/e02_solids/multiple_outputs.py).

However, you do not need `dagster_pandas`, rather, the key lines missing from your code are:

```py
if typing.TYPE_CHECKING:
    DataFrame = list
else:
    DataFrame = PythonObjectDagsterType(list, name="DataFrame")  # type: Any
```

The reason for the above structure is to achieve MyPy compliance, see the [Types & Expectations section](https://docs.dagster.io/tutorial/types#mypy-compliance) of the tutorial.

See also the documentation on [Dagster types](https://docs.dagster.io/overview/types).

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck here, too, but luckily I found the updated source code.
They have updated the docs so that the `OutputDefinition` is defined beforehand.

Update your code before sorting and pipeline like below:

```
import csv
import os

from dagster import (
    Bool,
    Field,
    Output,
    OutputDefinition,
    execute_pipeline,
    pipeline,
    solid,
)


@solid
def read_csv(context, csv_path):
    lines = []
    csv_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), csv_path)
    with open(csv_path, "r") as fd:
        for row in csv.DictReader(fd):
            row["calories"] = int(row["calories"])
            lines.append(row)

    context.log.info("Read {n_lines} lines".format(n_lines=len(lines)))
    return lines


@solid(
    config_schema={
        "process_hot": Field(Bool, is_required=False, default_value=True),
        "process_cold": Field(Bool, is_required=False, default_value=True),
    },
    output_defs=[
        OutputDefinition(name="hot_cereals", is_required=False),
        OutputDefinition(name="cold_cereals", is_required=False),
    ],
)
def split_cereals(context, cereals):
    if context.solid_config["process_hot"]:
        hot_cereals = [cereal for cereal in cereals if cereal["type"] == "H"]
        yield Output(hot_cereals, "hot_cereals")
    if context.solid_config["process_cold"]:
        cold_cereals = [cereal for cereal in cereals if cereal["type"] == "C"]
        yield Output(cold_cereals, "cold_cereals")
```

You can also find the whole lines of codes from [here](https://github.com/dagster-io/dagster/blob/master/examples/docs_snippets/docs_snippets/intro_tutorial/basics/e02_solids/multiple_outputs.py).

Answer (score -1):

Try first to install the dagster pandas integration:

```
pip install dagster_pandas
```

Then do:

```
from dagster_pandas import DataFrame
```

You can find the code from the tutorial [here](https://github.com/dagster-io/dagster/blob/4a91c9d09b50db93e9174c93a4ada0e138e3a046/examples/docs_snippets/docs_snippets/intro_tutorial/basics/e02_solids/multiple_outputs.py).